# PHP mySQL - Get data from 3 tables from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables with their columns, I would like to fetch those students who haven't taken the quiz and those who already took the quiz (separate scripts)

```
Table quiz
Column id, title, created_at, start_on, end_on, class_name, user_faculty

Table studentclass
Column id, class_name, user_faculty, user_student

Table score
Column id, grade, user_student, status, quiz_id
```

Where as quiz.class_name = studentclass.class_name, quiz.user_faculty = sctudentclass.user_faculty, studentclass.user_student = score.user_student and quiz.id = score.quiz_id

score.status = 'F' //this defines that the user_student already took the quiz

My query is:

```
SELECT quiz.id, quiz.title, quiz.start_on, quiz.end_on, quiz.class_name,
quiz.user_faculty, studentclass.user_student, score.status
FROM quiz
INNER JOIN studentclass
ON quiz.class_name = studentclass.class_name
AND start_on >= now()
AND end_on <= now()
LEFT JOIN score
ON quiz.id = score.quiz_id
WHERE score.status IS NULL
```

If the user_student already took the quiz then he is unable to see the quiz anymore because he already has a row in the score table with the user_student, quiz_id and status. But other user_student who haven't taken the quiz can see the quiz.

I hope you get what I want to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The following query would list all the student who havnt taken the quiz. Let me know if it serves your purpose. I'll update it as per the need.

You can add the joins accordingly if you want the data from other tables.

```
select * from studentclass Where id NOT IN (
     select user_student from score where quiz_id = YOUR ID //if you wnat to filter it for a specific quiz.
)
```

Comment: it didnt work for me, it is giving me all of the studentclass, I want to fetch the QUIZ, and will just need to STUDENTCLASS to compare for the class_name and user_student